# Load a form using ajax in Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use an ajax to show a form a site however I am losing the JQM styleing so it just show plain how can I get the form to show correctly? My code is below

```
 <div data-role="page" data-add-back-btn="true" id="events">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1 id='heading'></h1>
            <a href="#" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
        </div>    
    <div data-role="content" id="textcontent"></div>
 <li><a href="Javascript:form();">Contact Us</a></li>

function form()
{ 
alert("Success");
data = data + '<form action="index.html" method="post"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="username">Username<label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></form></div>'
$('#textcontent').html(data);
$('#textcontent').show();
 }
```

The function is called and the form appears on the screen but it loses all the jqm styling any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$(".ui-page").trigger("create");` as the last line in `form()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `trigger('create')` should do the trick.

```
function form(){ 
    data = '<form action="index.html" method="post"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label      for="username">Username<label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></div></form>';
    $('#textcontent').html(data);
    $('.ui-page').trigger('create');
    $('#textcontent').show();

}
```

A couple of other things that may help you would be

1. You have an html error in the form. Your div must close before your form does. i.e. `</div></form>` is how it should be. Also a `<li>` element should be wrapped in either a `<ul>` or an `<ol>`.
2. Get rid of data + in your from variable. I'm not sure what that is intended for.
3. Just put the form inside a div that is set to `display:none`. That way the trigger('create') method will be unnecessary. Then you can just show() or toggle() the visibility.

Comment: i tryed this but it still doesnt work my new form function is below

Comment: function form()
{ 
 alert("Success");
 $('#listcontent').hide();
 $('#heading').text("Contact Us");
 data = '<form action="index.html" method="post"><div data-role="fieldcontain"><label for="username">Username<label><input type="text" name="username" id="username"></div></form>'
 $('#textcontent').html(data);
 $('#textcontent').show();
}